# Creating LDAP Connection on .NET

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I am trying to Create LDAP Cnnection using c# .

I found this server which gives  LDAP Server to Test

http://www.forumsys.com/en/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/

I have googled many post and Tried to create a consolidated Code

```
  string domain = "ldap://ldap.forumsys.com/ou=mathematicians";
            string username = "cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com";
            string password = "password";
            string LdapPath = "Ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389/ou=scientists,dc=example,dc=com";


            string domainAndUsername = domain + @"\" + username;
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(LdapPath, domainAndUsername, password);
            try
            {
                // Bind to the native AdsObject to force authentication.
                Object obj = entry.NativeObject;
                DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
                search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + username + ")";
                search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
                SearchResult result = search.FindOne();

                // Update the new path to the user in the directory
                LdapPath = result.Path;
                string _filterAttribute = (String)result.Properties["cn"][0];
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw new Exception("Error authenticating user." + ex.Message);
            }
```

This code is not connecting it is giving unexpected error ..

I also Tried some other Credentials , But they are not helping either ...

```
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = “ldap://ldap.forumsys.com”
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = “cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com”
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = “password”
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch(“ou=mathematicians,dc=example,dc=com”,
ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, “(uid=%(user)s)”)

--------------------
$config[‘LDAP’][‘server’] = ‘ldap://ldap.forumsys.com';
$config[‘LDAP’][‘port’] = ‘389’;
$config[‘LDAP’][‘user’] = ‘cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com';
$config[‘LDAP’][‘password’] = ‘password';

-------------------------
$config[‘LDAP’][‘server’] = ‘ldap://ldap.forumsys.com/ou=mathematicians';
$config[‘LDAP’][‘port’] = ‘389’;
$config[‘LDAP’][‘user’] = ‘gauss';
$config[‘LDAP’][‘password’] = ‘password';

--------------------------
OpenDSObject/GetObject functions, but don’t see a way to run a query with the ASDI objects.
Set LDAP = GetObject(“LDAP:”)
Set root = LDAP.OpenDSObject(“LDAP://ldap.forumsys.com:389″, “cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com”, “password”, 0)
Set ou = LDAP.OpenDSObject(“LDAP://ldap.forumsys.com:389/ou=mathematicians,dc=example,dc=com””, “cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com”, “password”, 0)
Set user = LDAP.OpenDSObject(“LDAP://ldap.forumsys.com:389/uid=riemann,dc=example,dc=com”, “cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com”, “password”, 0)
```

I need some suggestion what I am missing . any resource will be helpful

Comment: **What** unexpected error?

Comment: Have you tried giving the correct protocol: LDAP instead of Ldap or ldap? According to this http://forums.asp.net/t/1026497.aspx?LDAP+Problem+with+NET+Unknown+error+0x80005000+ which I just googled, that can be a cause of issues.

Answer (score 5):

I had a somewhat similar issue with this server and google sent me here.

One issue I see is that case sensitive issue in LDAP path. Also we should specify the AuthenticationType as well.

Please check following code block which should work.

```
string ldapServer = "LDAP://ldap.forumsys.com:389/ou=scientists,dc=example,dc=com";
string userName = "cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com";
string password = "password";

var dirctoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ldapServer, userName, password, AuthenticationTypes.ServerBind);

try {
    object nativeObject = dirctoryEntry.NativeObject;
    //Rest of the logic
} catch (Exception ex) {
    //Handle error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying using PrincipalContext to connect to the LDAP server. Here is a good how-to article I referenced when I was getting started:  http://ianatkinson.net/computing/adcsharp.htm

```
ctx = new PrincipalContext(
    ContextType.Domain,
    "contoso.local",
    "OU=Security Groups,OU=Contoso Inc,DC=contoso,DC=local",
    "contoso\sysadmin",
    "P@ssword1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Namespace - using System.DirectoryServices.Protocols;

methode -

```
private bool ldapValidateUser(string fullname, string password)
        {
 
try
            {
                LdapDirectoryIdentifier ldap = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("Directory Host", true, false); 
                LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection(ldap);
                connection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;

                string ldapuser = "cn=" + fullname + ",ou=Org Unit,dc=Value,dc=local";
                connection.Credential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ldapuser, password);
                connection.Bind();
                
                return true;
            }


            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
     return false;
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).